# how to fixe 'Violation of Permissions policy' Issue in play store

Tags: javascript, java, android, google-play-services

My app was rejected for violating the Permissions policy.

```java
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```

how I can  registered as the default Phone or Assistant handler on the device.

Idon't know what I can Do to fix this Violation of Permissions policy Issue.

Comment: Did you add privacy policy into your app store while updating into google play sore?
If not go through [link]( https://www.iubenda.com/en/help/11552-privacy-policy-for-android-apps).

Comment: I added it and it didn't work